# Manipulate kernel device name with udev rules

Tags: linux, bash, device, udev

I have bash script that takes in an a KERNEL device name as an argument and outputs a new string that can be used as the new KERNEL device name.

```
Example: 
bash myScript sda
output: sdaa
```

I use custom udev rules for this purpose.

I am not sure how to pass an argument into a bash script and catch the resultant output using udev rules.

Here are some of the rules I have tried,

```
KERNEL=="sda", RUN+="/bin/bash /etc/udev/myScript '%E{KERNEL}'", NAME="%c"

KERNEL=="sda", IMPORT{program}="/bin/bash /etc/udev/myScript --export %k", NAME="%c"

KERNEL=="sda", IMPORT{program}="/bin/bash /etc/udev/myScript --import %k --export %c", NAME="%c"
```

I use an echo to output my string to the standard output.

Comment: Removed the duplicate question on server fault

Answer (score 0):

The device attributes can be passed to script via device properties (%k - device kernel name, %p - devpath of device). you can refer to Manual page of udev for all available device properties.

And std output from shell script is made available to udev rules by "%c". 
.

how about this rule:

```
KERNEL=="sda", RUN+="/bin/bash /etc/udev/myScript %k", NAME="%c"
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. /dev/sda is no longer present under /dev/. This means that some part of the script does some work, but /dev/sdaa is not created. My script is straight forward, contains only one line,  echo `echo $1 | sed "s/${1:2:1}/${1:2:1}${1:2:1}/"`

Comment: check if you can find any useful logs by changing log-level of udev. 
udevadm control --log-priority=debug

Comment: initally, just output some constant from script and see if it changes the device name.

Comment: I have devices sda and sdb. If I change sda's name to sdb, I don't see sda, but only see sdb. This means sda has become sdb. But if I try to change sda to something like backup, I don't see backup under /dev/

Comment: found any udev related logs(/var/log/messages), after enabling debug logs?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change the name of a device node. Only additional symlinks can be created.

If you assign a value to the `NAME` key you can only change the name of a network interface.

See [systemd udev documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html#NAME1). Same for the old [standalone udevd](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/hotplug/udev.git/tree/src/udev.xml#n316)